# How to Find Expected Value from a Joint Distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a random variable from a contaminated normal distribution.
>   That is, let $B ∼\text{Bernoulli}(p).$ Then $X|B = 0 ∼ N(µ, τ^2 )$ and $X|B = 1 ∼ N(µ, σ^2 )$.
>
> Calculate $\text{Cov}(X, B)$. Are $X$ and $B$ independent?

Here we know $\operatorname{Cov}(X,B)=E(XB)-E(X)E(B)$
Here i found $$E(X)=\mu$$ and $E(B)=p,$.
But how can I find E(XB)?

even if i can find $E(XB)$, then how to take decision that $X and B$ are independent or not because $Cov(X,B)=0$ doesn't imply they are independent.

Comment: $E(X)=E(X1_{B=0}+X1_{B=1})$, and you do the same for $E(XB)$. By the way, your $EX(X)$ is wrong.
The conclusion is wrong ,be careful. The nil covariance of two random variables does not imply the independence.

Comment: The passage "$E(X)=p+\mu,\text{ when } B=0$, $E(X)=\mu,\text{ when } B=1$" is, frankly speaking, absurd, since $E(X)$ cannot be equal to two different values simultaneously, right? Please reformulate. // To show the non-independence when $\sigma^2\ne\tau^2$, $p\ne0$ and $p\ne1$, one can turn to $E(X^2B)=(\mu^2+\sigma^2)p$ and $E(X^2)=\mu^2+p\sigma^2+(1-p)\tau^2$ hence the covariance of $X^2$ and $B$ is $p(1-p)(\tau^2-\sigma^2)\ne0$..

Comment: Thanks. My $E(X^2)$ is exactly like your one. But my $E(X^2B)=p(1-p){\tau^2}+p\mu^2+p^2\sigma^2$. I could not figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Well, $E(X^2B)=E(X^2B\mid B=0)P(B=0)+E(X^2B\mid B=1)P(B=1)$, that is, $E(X^2B)=E(0\mid B=0)(1-p)+E(X^2\mid B=1)p=\ldots$